# Ubuntu 14.04 & Windows VNC Program

Tags: vnc

A while back I updated Ubuntu to version 14.04. Before this, I could connect to the machine through TightVNC from my Windows 8.1 laptop.

However after the upgrade things didn't run smoothly. It is now a known bug that usual VNC software can't connect to Ubuntu 14.04 because it uses security TLS type (18), which TightVNC doesn't support.

My question is: is there any freeware available (for Windows) that does the job like TightVNC, but supports TLS security type 18?

The bug I report is mentioned [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1281250).

Answer (score 0):

I used x11vnc for the server and realvncviewer for windows. It doesn't works perfect but still better than nothing.